# Javascript form validation and if invalid no submission

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Frnds i need some help..
In this code i have validated the 2 textboxes. 
The help i need is once no data has been entered in the boxes the form should not goto check.php but with an javascript alert: Invalid Data
I need this in Javascript...

```
function f1()
{
    var v1=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var v2=document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(v1=="" || v2=="")
alert("Please Fill It..!");

}
```

```
Username:<input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="username" title="Enter your Username" name="uname"/>
Password:
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password" title="Enter your password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="clear"/>

</form>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing with the code you currently have?

Comment: what exactly is tha problem you are facing ???

Comment: Bro i am using < form action="check.php"> and even the onsubmit returned false check.php is executing....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function f1()
{
    var v1=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var v2=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if(v1=="" || v2=="") 
    {
         alert("Please Fill It..!");
         return false;
    }
}
```

The problem with your function is that by default it returns true and form is submitted. You need to return false in order to prevent form submit.

Comment: always consider providing description to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `onSubmit` which will run the javascript in it. If it returns a falsy value, the submit won't be made, but if it returns `true`, the submit will be made.

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return f1()">
Username:<input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="username" title="Enter your Username" name="uname"/>
Password:
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password" title="Enter your password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="clear"/>

</form>
```

f1 has to be a function that returns `true` or `false`

Comment: always consider providing description to your answer

Comment: But i had given <form action="check.php"> so if it return false will the php code runs...?

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your f1() as form onSubmit event handler.

```
<form action="formaction" method="post" onsubmit="f1()">
Username:<input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="username" title="Enter your Username" name="uname"/>
Password:
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password" title="Enter your password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="clear"/>
</form>

function f1()
{
    var v1=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var v2=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if(v1=="" || v2=="") return false;

}
```

Comment: But even the validation failed action is still in action

Comment: if "return false" is executed, there is no way the form can be submitted. You might want to debug into your form validation javascript to make sure the validation does fail and return false;